# angular-google-maps not showing infowindow on mouseover event

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-google-maps

I am using angularjs-google-map http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api

I can add multiple markers with showing infoWindow by cliking on a marker, but now I need to show the marker infoWindow when the mouse enters the area of the marker icon and hide it when the mouse leaves the area of the marker icon instead of using the click event.

You can look on this example on Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/meher12/bgb36q7b/ to get idea about my purpose !

My HTML code:

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"  dragging="map.dragging" bounds="map.bounds"
                events="map.events"  options="map.options" pan="true" control="map.control">    


            <ui-gmap-markers models="map.randomMarkers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'"
                doCluster="map.doClusterRandomMarkers" clusterOptions="map.clusterOptions" modelsbyref="true"
                events="map.markersEvents" options="'options'"
                >


                <ui-gmap-windows show="'showWindow'" ng-cloak>
                <div>
                    <p>This is an info window</p>
                </div>
            </ui-gmap-windows>


            </ui-gmap-markers>      

        </ui-gmap-google-map>


  </div>
```

My JS code:

```
myApp.controller('MainController', function ($scope,uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

    $scope.numOfMarkers = 25;
uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function(maps) { $scope.googleVersion = maps.version; });



    $scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 45,
            longitude: -73
        },
        zoom: 10,
        options: {
            streetViewControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            maxZoom: 20,
            minZoom: 3
        },
        dragging: false,
        bounds: {},

        randomMarkers: [],
        doClusterRandomMarkers: true,
        currentClusterType: 'standard',
        clusterOptions: {
            title: 'Hi I am a Cluster!', gridSize: 60, ignoreHidden: true, minimumClusterSize: 2
        }

    };

     $scope.map.markersEvents = {
        mouseover: function (marker, eventName, model, args) {
          model.options.labelContent = "Position - lat: " + model.latitude + " lon: " + model.longitude;
          marker.showWindow = true;
          $scope.$apply();
        },
        mouseout: function (marker, eventName, model, args) {
           model.options.labelContent = " ";
           marker.showWindow = false;
           $scope.$apply();
        }
    };


    var genRandomMarkers = function (numberOfMarkers, scope) {
        var markers = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < numberOfMarkers; i++) {
          markers.push(createRandomMarker(i, scope.map.bounds))
      }
      scope.map.randomMarkers = markers;
  };

     var createRandomMarker = function (i, bounds, idKey) {
     var lat_min = bounds.southwest.latitude,
  lat_range = bounds.northeast.latitude - lat_min,
  lng_min = bounds.southwest.longitude,
  lng_range = bounds.northeast.longitude - lng_min;

if (idKey == null)
  idKey = "id";

var latitude = lat_min + (Math.random() * lat_range);
var longitude = lng_min + (Math.random() * lng_range);
var ret = {
  latitude: latitude,
  longitude: longitude,
  title: 'm' + i,
  showWindow: false,
  options: {
        labelContent: ' ',
        labelAnchor: "22 0",
        labelClass: "marker-labels",
        draggable: true
      }
};
ret[idKey] = i;
return ret;
};


   $scope.genRandomMarkers = function (numberOfMarkers) {
      genRandomMarkers(numberOfMarkers, $scope);
  };
   $scope.removeMarkers = function () {

    $scope.map.randomMarkers = [];

 };

});
```

Like you see on my JS code I have created markerEvents and I can get the marker label changed on mouse events but still not showing the infoWindow attached to each marker on the map when the mouse Event is fired, despite its value is changing and take the correct value.

Someone Have an idea to resolve this issue ? 
Feel free to put your changes to my Jsfiddle code :)

Comment: I must be missing something... where in your code are you opening InfoWindows?  All I see is you setting `marker.showWindow = true;`.  Maybe I don't understand Angular, but isn't there some code which is checking for `showWindow `?

Comment: Yes if you don't understand well AngularJS, you'll have constraints to detect the issue. However, I have just found the solution and it works as I wanted, I've also added changes to the jsFiddle code that I posted https://jsfiddle.net/meher12/bgb36q7b/30/ 
Thank you for your support.

Comment: @MeherHedhli Thanks for  highlighting this, am implementing the same but was wondering if you want to add one marker without removing the older ones, i tried pushing new item to the array but the changes doesn't reflect on the map!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must set `model.showWindow` instead of `marker.showWindow`

Comment: Yes that's what I had to do and I detect it after posting my question, it works now by setting model.showWindow instead of marker.showWindow.  Thank's :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `model.show = true` instead of `model.showWindow`, in html remove `show =showWindow`.